# create tar file programatically in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a directory into tar file, which includes an empty sub-directory and sub-directories with some .json file, using Java's JTar. Folders that contain files are automatically included in the .tar file, but the empty folders are not.I want to create .tar file with all(empty and with data init) the sub directories.
My code is this way:

```
try
        {
            File tarFile = new File("somefilename.tar");
            TarOutputStream tos = new TarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tarFile));

            tartar("directoryname", tos);
            tos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
private static void tartar(String dir, TarOutputStream tos)
    {
        File f = new File(dir);
        String[] flist = f.list();
        int buffersize = 1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[buffersize];
        for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++)
        {
            File f2 = new File(f, flist[i]);
            if (f2.isDirectory())
            {
                tartar(f2.getPath(), tos);
                continue;
            }
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f2);
                // TarEntry te = new TarEntry(f2.getPath());
                TarEntry te = new TarEntry(f2, f2.getPath());
                tos.putNextEntry(te);
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = fis.read(buf, 0, buffersize)) != -1)
                {
                    tos.write(buf, 0, count);
                }
                // tos.closeEntry();
                // tos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

While I have not worked with invoking tarball in Java, but in Linux you can run command "tar -cvzf file_name.tar.gz directory_name/" using Runtime, Process and ProcessBuilder API.

Comment: @Huke, i want to create .tar folder programatically and from above posted code i am able to create .tar file but problem is it is skipping empty directory.

Comment: Hmm, I see, because empty directory will not have files, so `String[] flist = f.list();` will return empty array. And you wont be able to go inside loop after it.

Comment: So, check array length. If it is empty, then just create that directory entry in TAR, if its not empty then loop through each files and create entries.

Comment: String[] flist; gives list of sub-directories present and its working.